# Noticação Push no Android com OneSignal - Ação em segundo plano

Tags: java, android, firebase, api

tenho em minha aplicação android o serviço OneSignal funcionando corretamente, até aqui tudo bem. Quero fazer algumas modificações no meu SharePreference (banco de dados) a cada vez que recebo uma mensagem. Consegui fazer tal ação enquanto o aplicativo está em primeiro plano, no entanto em segundo plano a ação não funciona. Gostaria então que me ajudassem a resolver esse problema. Segue o código que funciona em primeiro prano

```
public class mIntentService extends IntentService {
    public mIntentService() {
        super("notification");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(MyApplication.getAppContext())
                .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new NotificationReceivedHandler())
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();


        Log.i("notification", "O IntentService foi iniciado");
    }

    public class NotificationReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {
        @Override
        public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {

            //Essa é a função após receber a notificação
            LibraryIO io = new LibraryIO(getApplicationContext());
            io.setBooleanIO("iconNotificationNews", true);
            Log.i("iconNotificationNews", "iconNotificationNews chamadado");
        }
    }
}
```

Observe que tentei jogar em um service, mas ainda não entendo como funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema e está funcionando perfeitamente, segue a solução encontrada no seguinte endereço: [Documentação](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations)

segue meu código:

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import com.edesonabizerril.newintercampi.data_and_utils.LibraryIO;
import com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationDisplayedResult;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationReceivedResult;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class mIntentService extends NotificationExtenderService{

    @Override
    protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
    LibraryIO io = new LibraryIO(getApplicationContext());
    io.setBooleanIO("iconNotificationNews", true);
    Log.i("iconNotificationNews", "iconNotificationNews chamadado");

    OverrideSettings overrideSettings = new OverrideSettings();
    overrideSettings.extender = new NotificationCompat.Extender() {
        @Override
        public NotificationCompat.Builder extend(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
            // Sets the background notification color to Green on Android 5.0+ devices.
            Log.i("iconNotificationNews", "iconNotificationNews chamadado 2");
            return builder.setColor(new BigInteger("0d2541", 16).intValue());
        }
    };

    OSNotificationDisplayedResult displayedResult = displayNotification(overrideSettings);
    Log.d("OneSignalExample", "Notification displayed with id: " + displayedResult.androidNotificationId);
    Log.i("iconNotificationNews", "iconNotificationNews chamadado 3");
    return true;
    }
}
```

Na tela principal temos:

```
// OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(MyApplication.getAppContext())
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
```

E abaixo de todas as Activities há o seguinte código no arquivo de manifesto

```
<service
            android:name=".services.mIntentService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```